# Correctness of ERD diagrams

Tags: database, relational-database, entity

I am new to database modeling.Here is a problem I was trying to solve:

Information about movies,stars and studios.Movies are shot in studios that own them.A movie is shot in only one studio.Stars are connected to one or more studios but can act in any film that may or may not be owned by the studio.Stars can act in any number of films in a given year.

Here is the diagram I made.Note that   -----> means 1:N relationship with N on the > side.
[image: ERD diagram]

Am I correct?Should there be any weak entities?Should there be any total participation?

Comment: Just a general observation - you have a single "studio" entity, yet you really have two different ideas. First, there is the physical studio (or stage) where films are made. Then you have the idea of the business entity of a studio. I would separate these.  And in many cases, these business studios "own" the stars as well, but they may allow them to work for other studios subject to a contract.

Answer (score 1):

I consider 1:N relationships an optimization, and, you know that they say: that premature optimization is an evil, a bad code smell, etc...

So, my recommendation is to use N:M relationships between all entities until you have firm grasp of both:

1. the (as we know, ever-changing) business model, and,
2. your actual performance limitations in real-world conditions.

Unoptimized code/data is less brittle to change, easier to maintain.  (Consider what will happen when two studios collaborate on a movie?)

---

On the subject of 1:N relationships:

First, I would recommend using an industry standard tool for creating and sharing your diagrams.

Second, you should make the order of reading the relationships follow the arrows, or else have a separate reading order for the relationships independent of the direction of the 1:N.  Consider the "Own" relationship as you are showing it.  I read it as N Movie(s) Own 1 Studio, but that isn't proper as 1 Studio Owns N Movies.  As I mentioned, you can fix that by using Is-Owned-By instead of Own(s), or, by having Own(s) indicate that the subject/object are to be read in reverse.

---

Also, I might add that you may have more relationships than you need, so, you should try to delve further into your business/domain requirements.  The "Own" is duplicative of "Shot In", and, Connected To is also perhaps unnecessary, as one could derive that an actor/actress was associated with a studio by the movies they made, as the movies are associated with studios.

Materializing derived relationships also falls under the category of (premature) optimization.  They incur programming overhead, increase consistency requirements, and make your code harder to maintain in the long run.

Comment: I really do not think m:n relationships are the way to go. In any database ever, decomposition has always proved to be the lesser evil.

Comment: @David, if a 1:1 or 1:N is coming as a business requirement, then ok.  However, it is all too easy for a programmer to build in assumptions about 1:N that don't actually model the business.  Sometimes it takes a long time before a rare case reveals that the business actually requires a NxM.  For example, each professor has their own office, broken when two share an office due to running out of space; each professor is in one department, broken when a professor teaches both biology and physics, she is in two departments and has two offices...

Comment: I think this is a great answer, and the premature hardening of virtual or abstract relationships is indeed a plague upon data models in general.